# Prevent Excel converting number range to Date format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel to translate data from one system which outputs .csv files to another which can read in .xls files. One column is sizes, which frequently includes terms like 4-6, 6-8, etc.  When the csv is opened in Excel, these are automatically(?) converted to dates (6-Apr, 8-Jun, etc.)  I can use
.NumberFormat = "m-d"
to get the data to *look like it should, but of course it's still a date value, and any operations I try to perform with it convert back to date.  Is there any way to convert it to text in exactly that format?  If I declare the .NumberFormat as "@", it just changes the value to a serial. I use the size, along with several other columns to create one long product ID code for inventory purposes.... when the size changes to a date value, I end up missing some of the data.

Comment: Read the csv file in as a text file and then do a "text to columns" (using comma as the delimiter), specifying that that column should remain as text.

Comment: I am trying to create a "fire and forget" program for others to run, and want to avoid any special open/import instructions if possible. It just seems like such a bug in Excel that this setting can't be easily overridden.   Oddly, the Concatenate function in Excel will produce the correct result, but not in VBA. `=CONCATENATE(month(A1),"-",day(A1))`

Comment: There is no reason that reading the csv file as a text file and doing a "text to columns" can't be a "fire and forget" application - as far as the users are concerned, it's a button press no matter what code that button uses.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem that runs entirely from VBA - i.e., doesn't depend on special import conditions.  I would appreciate any pointers or recommendations, especially if this has the potential to create unforeseen errors:

```
Dim Size as String
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsDate(Range("H" & i).Value) Then
        Size = Month(Range("H" & i)) & "-" & Day(Range("H" & i))
        Range("H" & i).NumberFormat = "@"
        Range("H" & i) = Size
    End If
Next i
```

The column I'm testing includes size values that are string (XL, SM, 12T, etc), along with values that get converted to dates (4-6, 6-8). This *seems* to convert it back to a string value, and then properly treats it as a string value on all future uses (concatenations and logical tests)